How to put a border-radius to a field set with a gradient on the border?
I'm stuck with this css issue:
I have to create a block, with a transparent background, rounded corners, a gradient on the border and a "border cut" under the title.
here is the design :
enter image description here
I used a fieldset to have this "border cut". There is no problem when I put a single color to the border but once I put the gradient as a border-image, the border-radius is cancelled...
enter image description here
enter image description here


.fieldset_contour_block {
  position: relative;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red) 1;
  border-radius: 30px;
  .titre_legend_block {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
<fieldset class="fieldset_contour_block">
  <legend class="titre_legend_block">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </legend>
</fieldset>



Any ideas?
Thanks!

share your code example

Code added, thanks for your comments

Please have a look at the following question: Possible to use border-radius together with a border-image which has a gradient?

Thanks but I have no issue applying a border radius to an item with a gradient on the border that is not a fieldset, but I need the fieldset/legend combination property. Or another way to apply that property to another element

Did you even try to test the answers? fast demo

Whaou awesome! Will test that right now

I need a transparent background, not a white or another color ;-) Actually I'm not sur this is possible

based on the duplicate: https://jsfiddle.net/jwo6v5ux/

Thanks @TemaniAfif, this is not exactly what I'm looking for but it's a good track to dig further. I'll let you know if I manage something with your code
